# Magnification API: flickering during repaint

Tags: c, winapi, drawing, flicker, magnification-api

I created an application by slightly modifying the [Magnification API sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Magnification/cpp/Windowed/MagnifierSample.cpp) provided by Microsoft to implement a custom transformation of each frame captured and displayed in the Magnifier window.

I used the `MagSetImageScalingCallback` to set the my function as a callback. The callback is invoked without problem and the source and destination image can be easily manipulated because the raw bits are passed to the callback as pointers (srcdata and destdata).

The window is refreshed with a timer which is set to 16 ms (~60Hz). The refresh is invoked by using the `InvalidateRect` API. The problem is that when the magnifier window suffer from flickering. This happens especially when the start menu appears, if "Peek" is enabled or every time there is a window on foreground which has dynamic content.

I tried to intercept the **WM_ERASEBKGND** and invoke the `InvalidateRect` with FALSE as third parameter but this didn't help. I tried to add an `UpdateWindow` invocation before the invalidate but nothing changed.

The Magnifier application provided with Windows 10 doesn't have the same problem. I'm wondering why this is happening and how can I get rid of flickering.

In order to reproduce che problem download the Magnification API sample from the link above then replace the content in the file **MagnifierSample.cpp** with this source code:

```
// Ensure that the following definition is in effect before winuser.h is included.
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501    
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <magnification.h>

// For simplicity, the sample uses a constant magnification factor.
#define RESTOREDWINDOWSTYLES WS_POPUP

// Global variables and strings.
HINSTANCE           hInst;
const TCHAR         WindowClassName[]= TEXT("MagnifierWindow");
const TCHAR         WindowTitle[]= TEXT("Screen Magnifier Sample");
const UINT          timerInterval = 16; // close to the refresh rate @60hz
HWND                hwndMag;
HWND                hwndHost;
RECT                magWindowRect;
RECT                hostWindowRect;

// Forward declarations.
ATOM                RegisterHostWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                SetupMagnifier(HINSTANCE hinst);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void CALLBACK       UpdateMagWindow(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime);
BOOL                isFullScreen = FALSE;

//
// FUNCTION: WinMain()
//
// PURPOSE: Entry point for the application.
//
int APIENTRY WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
                     _In_ LPSTR     /*lpCmdLine*/,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    if (FALSE == MagInitialize())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (FALSE == SetupMagnifier(hInstance))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwndHost, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwndHost);

    // Create a timer to update the control.
    UINT_PTR timerId = SetTimer(hwndHost, 0, timerInterval, UpdateMagWindow);

    // Main message loop.
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Shut down.
    KillTimer(NULL, timerId);
    MagUninitialize();
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//
// FUNCTION: HostWndProc()
//
// PURPOSE: Window procedure for the window that hosts the magnifier control.
//
LRESULT CALLBACK HostWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) 
    {
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            return TRUE;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;  
}

//
//  FUNCTION: RegisterHostWindowClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class for the window that contains the magnification control.
//
ATOM RegisterHostWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = {};

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX); 
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = HostWndProc;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(1 + COLOR_BTNFACE);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = WindowClassName;

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

static BOOL CALLBACK myCallBack(HWND hwnd, void *srcdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER srcheader, void *destdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER destheader, RECT unclipped, RECT clipped, HRGN dirty) {

    UINT row;
    UINT column;
    BYTE *matrix;

    memset(destdata, 0, destheader.cbSize);
    matrix = (BYTE *) destdata;

    //Set alpha bits for the resulting image to 255 (fully opaque)
    for (row = 0; row < destheader.height; row++) {

        for (column = 3; column < destheader.width; column += 4) {

            matrix[(row * destheader.width) + column] = 0xFF;
        }
    }

    Sleep(20);
    return TRUE;
}


//
// FUNCTION: SetupMagnifier
//
// PURPOSE: Creates the windows and initializes magnification.
//
BOOL SetupMagnifier(HINSTANCE hinst)
{
    // Set bounds of host window according to screen size.
    hostWindowRect.top = 0;
    hostWindowRect.bottom = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    hostWindowRect.left = 0;
    hostWindowRect.right = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);

    // Create the host window.
    RegisterHostWindowClass(hinst);
    hwndHost = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED, WindowClassName, WindowTitle, RESTOREDWINDOWSTYLES, 0, 0, hostWindowRect.right, hostWindowRect.bottom, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    if (!hwndHost)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Make the window opaque.
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwndHost, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
    SetWindowLong(hwndHost, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwndHost, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);

    // Create a magnifier control that fills the client area.
    magWindowRect = hostWindowRect;
    hwndMag = CreateWindow(WC_MAGNIFIER, TEXT("MagnifierWindow"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, magWindowRect.left, magWindowRect.top, magWindowRect.right, magWindowRect.bottom, hwndHost, NULL, hInst, NULL );

    if (!hwndMag)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    MagSetImageScalingCallback(hwndMag, &myCallBack);
    // Set the source rectangle for the magnifier control.
    MagSetWindowSource(hwndMag, magWindowRect);

    return 1;  
}


//
// FUNCTION: UpdateMagWindow()
//
// PURPOSE: Sets the source rectangle and updates the window. Called by a timer.
//
void CALLBACK UpdateMagWindow(HWND /*hwnd*/, UINT /*uMsg*/, UINT_PTR /*idEvent*/, DWORD /*dwTime*/)
{
    // Reclaim topmost status, to prevent unmagnified menus from remaining in view. 
    SetWindowPos(hwndHost, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, magWindowRect.right, magWindowRect.bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOREDRAW);

    // Force redraw.
    InvalidateRect(hwndMag, NULL, FALSE);
}
```

Notice that I added the code to set the callback

```
BOOL ret = MagSetImageScalingCallback(hwndMag, &myCallBack);
```

then I created this callback:

```
static BOOL CALLBACK myCallBack(HWND hwnd, void *srcdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER srcheader, void *destdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER destheader, RECT unclipped, RECT clipped, HRGN dirty)
```

The `Sleep` statement "simulate" the time taken by my custom transformation.

If you open a youtube video with Edge and then you run the **MagnifierSample.exe** executable you should see a black screen flickering sometime and when the screen flickers you should see the content behind the magnifier window (the black screen). This is exactly what is happening in my application. The sleep value is set to 20 but I don't known how long the callback is actually taking. I just guessed that it might take more than 16 ms.

To reproduce the problem perform the following steps:

1. Run the MagnifierSample.exe manually (don't use the debugger to run it)
2. You should see a black screen
3. Press the window key
4. Set a window with a video or a dynamic content in foreground
5. Click on the black window to let the taskbar disappear
6. You should see the screen flashing sometime

Is it possible to set a callback similar to the `MagSetImageScalingCallback` for a normal window  handle ? I know I can use the WindowProc callback to intercept the messages sent to the window however I don't have access to the rawbits unless I use `CreateDIBSection`, `SelectObject` etc ...but at that time the image has been already sent to the destination window and I don't have the chance to transform it.

Comment: From [mcve]: *"Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem **in the question itself**"*.

Comment: @IInspectable I put the code inside the post. Now you can copy, paste, build and run the sample. You still need to download the sample unless you want to manually create a VS Solution and manually add all the required linker parameters.

Comment: I thought that the alpha channel in the destination image was causing the flickering so I tried to set it to 255 in the "myCallBack" callback but it didn't help.

Comment: You're redrawing your window twice: Once in response to `SetWindowPos` (without the `SWP_NOREDRAW` flag), and another time in response to the invalidation. Is that intentional?

Comment: No this is not intentional. I didn't know that SetWindowPos would cause the window to redraw even if the size and position haven't changed. I will let you know if adding SWP_NOREDRAW solve the problem.

Comment: The flasg SWP_NOREDRAW doesn't solve the problem. Note that even if the MagSetImageScalingCallback is commented (no callback is invoked and you just see the content of the screen mirrored) the window is still flickering sometimes. So there must be something wrong with the Magnification API.

Comment: I debugged your modified code and found no flicker. Even if I played a YouTube video and executed the EXE file, I could only stare at the black computer screen, but I didn't find any flicker. Please tell me if there is anything missing.

Comment: Note that the flickering is not constant. You should see like a flash and then black for most of the time. Did you wait for at least one minute ? Did you try to increase the Sleep value from 20 to a greater value ? Also make sure that the .exe is run manually (don't use the debugger to run it) and set the window with the video in foreground just after the launch. The windows key can help in achieving that. If you press the key the taskbar should appera on the bottom of the black screen. Click on the desired window icon then click on the black window to let the taskbar disappear.

Comment: It is not always easy to reproduce the problem. I have compared the official example. I suggest you put `MagSetWindowSource(hwndMag, magWindowRect)` in `void CALLBACK UpdateMagWindow()`, and try to call `WM_ERASEBKGND` to avoid background redraw. Refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3cf0155f-af7b-4c94-b21f-7dbd8c7e41e5/invalidate-make-my-screen-flicker-and-no-solution-can-be-found-to-help-me?forum=vcgeneral).

Comment: MagSetWindowSource can be called once because the captured area is always the same. In fact I tried to include it in the UpdateMagWindow call but it doesn't solve the problem. The WM_ERASEBKGND message is already handled in the HostWndProc callback.

Comment: When the screen flickers I noticed that the content shown behind the black window is not always the same. Sometimes I see the topmost window, sometimes I see just a white background and sometimes I can even see the desktop. It seems like if the window composition is compromised or disturbed by the fullscreen window.

Comment: I tried your updated code, but I can't reproduce your problem. Have you tried your code on other computers?

Comment: Yes I tried it on a virtual machine and on a laptop where the flickering is more visible. Of course both are Windows 10.

Comment: I made a dump of the messages dispatched to the window (while loop) and I discovered that the sequence is (WM_TIMER, WM_PAINT, WM_PAINT,WM_TIMER, WM_PAINT, WM_PAINT ...) So the WM_PAINT message is sent two times.

Comment: Hi, what is your Window10 version? I use the latest version of Window10 1903 to test, but I didn't see the flickering. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the version, but it's worth thinking about.

Comment: I have the latest 1909 on the physical computer and the 1809 on the VM. I upgraded the VM to 1909 too and now if RDP to this machine I can't even see the black window when I run the sample (It seem like if the window is not created). Same binary is working instead on the physical computer and the physical session of the VM (not RDP).

Comment: hi, has your problem be solved?

Comment: No unfortunately I still reproduce the problem on some computers. I tried to use the WS_CLIPCHILDREN in the main window but I only get a gray window and myCallBack is never triggered. I tried to raise the process priority and comment the SetWindowPos call, I tried also handling the WM_PAINT in HostWndProc with a "return TRUE" but I still see the flickering. I noticed that in some computers especially those with embededded video cards I can't reproduce the problem while in others I hit the problem.

Comment: What happens if you call DwmFlush() between every repaint?